# How to do np.where in node js for template matching with with node-opencv

Tags: python, node.js, numpy, opencv

I have this code that does exactly what I want in python:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv2.imread('large.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('small.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.9
print(res)
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
print(loc)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imwrite('res.png',img_rgb)
```

I am using [node-opencv](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv) and up to now I have this code:

```
const cv = require('opencv');

cv.readImage("./samples/profileImgs/large.jpg", function (err, largeImg) {
    const res = largeImg.matchTemplate("./samples/profileImgs/small.jpg", 0);
    console.log(res);
});
```

Which outputs:

> [ [ Matrix 1044x1820 ], 185, 68, 101, 37 ]

I would like to know how to do `np.where( res >= threshold)` to the Matrix in js, any libraries that are equivalent?

Comment: `lodash/underscore` provide a lot of iterative shortcuts for `javascript`

Comment: @hpaulj I have gone though the docs, but I am not sure exactly how to iterate through the Matrix that node-opencv returns, it;s not like it taks the structure just like that AFAIK, or maybe it does, I'm not sure how to handle it.

Comment: `lodash` works with stock JS structures.  I can't tell how `cv.Matrix` relates to those.  I suspect your answer lies entirely with the `node-opencv` package.